# 6 Grid DIVs with 2 Content DIVs each and toggle-Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ok, i might not seeing the wood for the trees - so here's my (probably easily solveable) problem:

i have this markup (6x times "col-4"-DIV with content):

```
<div class="partner inner">
 <div class="col-4">
  <div class="logo" id="logo-one"></div>
  <div class="caption hidden">
   <h3>Company One</h3>
   <address>
     Some Addressinfo here...
   </address>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS Situation:
each id from class "logo" has a background-image which switches the background-position vertically on hover.
class caption is hidden on default through helper-class "hidden"

What i want to achieve:
using jQuery to toggle Class "hidden" to the clicked logo.
using jQuery to toggle the div "caption" to show the addressinfo for each company.

My problem with this jQuery code:

```
        $(".logo").click(function(){
        $(".hidden").toggle(500);
        $(this).toggleClass("hidden");
    });
```

is that ALL logos disappear and only the clicked addressinfo is shown.

How can i achieve that only the logo clicked disappears and the addressinfo behind the clicked-logo is shown?

i'm probably just missing some easy step but i don't want to write 6 click-functions for each id - that would be too messy and probably not the right way am i right?

Comment: What is $(this) referring to?

Comment: well, i think it must be .logo - thats why all logos disappear after clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're targeting all elements with class `.hidden`.
You need to target the `.hidden` element related to the logo you've just clicked.
Since `.logo` and `.hidden` are siblings you can do :

```
$(this).siblings('.hidden').toggle(500);
```

Comment: this seems to work, but doesn't hide the .logo-div and only shows the .caption-div.

Comment: Did you replace the whole code with I've written? That line is only for the .hidden div part. You need to keep the rest..

    $(".logo").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.hidden').toggle(500);
        $(this).toggleClass("hidden");
    });

Comment: sorry, my fault. that actually works brilliant. 

can i add .caption to the $(".logo").click(function() without destryoing the funcionality?

cause it should also work the other way round (if you click on the address-info it should flip to the logo again except if you click on the Anchor to their Webpage).

Comment: just add .caption to the jquery selector so it becomes $('.logo, .caption').click();

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$(this).next('.hidden')
```

or even

```
$(this).parent().find('.hidden')
```